# Remove Low Quality Posts for questions altogether

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

There are two review queues on Stack Exchange that are used to decide if questions should be closed: Close Votes and Low Quality Posts. They are *very* similar to each other. The only differences I'm aware of are:

- They have different names.
- One of the buttons is named Looks OK in Low Quality Posts and Leave Open in Close Votes.
- In LQP, questions take a variable number of Looks OK reviews to be removed from review, whereas they always take 3 Leave Open reviews in CV.
- LQP can be accessed with 2k reputation, whereas CV requires 3k.

My proposal is to prevent questions from being added to Low Quality Posts altogether. Instead, we should send all questions that would normally go to Low Quality Posts to Close Votes review. This comes with a number of advantages, some of which are:

- **It gives Low Quality Posts a more specialized focus.** Reviewers in LQP can completely focus on reviewing answers, and users interested in deciding if questions should be closed have their own separate queue rather than having items scattered across 2 different queues.
- **It keeps all reviews of each type in the same place.** A lot of times, especially when looking through question timelines, I find that some reviews were performed in Low Quality Posts, and some reviews were done in Close Votes. It's inconvenient and confusing to have to go through multiple review tasks to see how the outcome was achieved.
- **It makes sure that users don't get unfair extra reviews.** The current system sometimes allows users to review a question as Looks OK in LQP *and* Leave Open in CV. This unfairly doubles the weight of the user's opinion that the question should not be closed.
- **It gets rid of "Recommend Close".** Users reviewing in LQP without enough reputation to [cast close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) have the Recommend Close button instead. This casts a close flag instead of a close vote like the Close button does for privileges users. Unlike Recommend Deletion, Recommend Close does not get the question any closer to getting closed because the only thing close flags do is send the post to a review queue, but it's already in the Low Quality Posts queue.

What do you think? Should we remove/eradicate/eliminate/abolish/discard Low Quality Posts for questions?

Comment: I do not understand this: *This unfairly doubles the weight of the user's opinion that the question should not be closed*.

Comment: @StephenRauch users can vote to Leave Open in Close Votes *and* review as Looks OK in Low Quality Posts. This makes it closer to exiting review in *both* queues, which, in a way, doubles the weight of the user's opinion. Here's an example where I unknowingly did this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/326867/timeline.

Comment: Stack Overflow has only answers in the LQP review queue; low-quality questions end up in the Triage / Help & Improvement queues. I don't think that experiment was really successful, and not having those queues at all would've made it even worse.

Comment: What about allowing questions to be deleted from the LQP queue too?

Comment: Also access to the LQP queue is given at a lower reputation than to the CV queue.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard to your first comment: except in a few rare cases, questions have to be closed before being deleted. I'm not sure it's such a good idea to allow reviewers to bypass the closing in LQP. To your second comment: yes, LQP requires 2k and CV requires 3k. I'll edit that into my question.

Comment: So would you keep LQP queue for answers but divert LQ questions to Close Votes?

Comment: @mdewey that is correct.